# Knex js, sqlite database won't update unless submitted twice

Tags: javascript, sqlite, knex.js

I have a table called "accounts" and I want to update column called "balance" when the column "total" is edited. When I submit the data it only updates the "total" column. But if I submit it again (twice) then column  "balance"  is updated.

Here is the code:

````
```function updateOne(id, job) {
  return db
    .transaction(function (t) {
      return db("jobs")
        .where({ id })
        .transacting(t)
        .select()
        .update({
          job_title: job.job_title,
          job_description: job.job_description,
          in_progress: job.in_progress,
          due_date: job.due_date,
          customer_id: job.customer_id,
          assigned_to: job.assigned_to,
          admin_id: job.admin_id,
          updated_at: timestamp,
        })
        .then(() => {
          return db("payments")
            .transacting(t)
            .sum("amount_paid as sum")
            .where("account_id", id);
        })
        .then((amountPaid) => {
          let { sum } = amountPaid[0];
          return db("accounts")
            .transacting(t)
            .where({ id })
            .update({
              total: job.total,
              balance: db.raw(`total - ${sum}`),
            });
        })
        .then(t.commit)
        .catch(t.rollback);
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("transaction succeeded ", id);
      return findById(id);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("transaction failed", err);
    });```
````

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code like this and it works. I deleted the account table and doing the calculation from job table -> balance column.

```
async function update(id, job) {
  try {
    await db.transaction(async (trx) => {
      const ids = await trx("job")
        .where("job.id", id)
        .update(
          {
            title: job.title,
            description: job.description,
            inProgress: job.inProgress,
            dueDate: job.dueDate,
            customerId: job.customerId,
            userId: job.userId,
            adminId: job.adminId,
            total: job.total,
            updatedAt: timestamp,
          },
          "id"
        )
        .transacting(trx);

      const payment = await trx("payment")
        .where("payment.jobId", ids[0].id)
        .update(
          {
            updatedAt: timestamp,
            userId: job.userId,
            paymentType: job.paymentType,
            amountPaid: job.amountPaid,
            editedBy: job.adminId,
          },
          ["id", "jobId"]
        )
        .transacting(trx);
      const [result] = payment;

      // Calculate all payments
      const paymentTotal = await trx("payment")
        .where("jobId", result.jobId)
        .sum("amountPaid as sum")
        .transacting(trx);

      let sum = paymentTotal[0].sum;
      // Calculate the new balance
      const balance = await trx("job")
        .where("id", result.jobId)
        .update({
          balance: db.raw(`job.total - ${sum}`),
        })
        .transacting(trx);
      
      return findById(ids[0].id);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```